# optimal code (in terms of memory usage) for list of sliced dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm collecting a list of dataframes as a result of querying multiple similar SQL tables. I do some processing on them, collect them in a list and in the end concatenate them. My code looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframes = []
for t in table_list:
    .
    .
    .
    dataframes.append(temp_df[["Name", "Value", "Date"]])
final_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
```

From what I understand of how Pandas works (and please correct me if I'm wrong), slicing a dataframe this way doesn't actually create a new dataframe but somehow points towards a subset of the original dataframe.

With that in mind, would it be better to do actually create a copy of the sub-dataframe and store that in the list instead? Namely, something like:

```
dataframes.append(temp_df[["Name", "Value", "Date"]].copy(deep=True))
```

Would that make any difference in terms of memory usage or execution time? In my mind if you had good garbage collection in my current version you would use considerably more memory than in the new version. Does it actually work that way though?